# How to find error on script using Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, scriptdom, tsql-parser

I have a SQL script `X Select top 1 * from table`. I use `MicrosoftSql.Smo` to check script has error or not. The letter X is incorrect for SQL script. But it cannot find the error in the script and evaluates as true. How can I solve this problem. Instead of using `GetTokenStream`, I also used `Parse` method. Nothing has been changed.

```
IList<ParseError> parseErrors;
TSql140Parser tsqlParser = new TSql140Parser(true);
IList<TSqlTokenStream> tStream;
using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(script))
            {
                tStream= (TSqlFragment)tsqlParser.GetTokenStream(stringReader, out parseErrors);
            }
if (parseErrors.Count > 0)
{
   var retMessage = string.Empty;
   foreach (var error in parseErrors)
   {
     throw new Exception("error in script")
   }
}
return (TSqlScript)fragment;
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a grammar error.

The script

```
X Select top 1 * from [table]
```

is just treated the same as

```
EXEC X;

Select top 1 * from [table];
```

SQL Server allows the term `EXEC` to be omitted in the first statement in a batch so it just interprets it as you trying to execute a stored procedure called `X`

Comment: And name deferral means it will only notice at runtime that it doesn't exist...